# How to click a button by twill?

Tags: python, html, authentication, twill

I want to go to a site and click on a button or link for logging in. But login does not use form.

I think login procedure use javascript.

Input for username:

```
    <input tabindex="1" 
class="dxeEditArea_Office2003Blue dxeEditAreaSys" onkeydown="aspxEKeyDown('ctl00_wucLogin1_txtUID', event)" 
    name="ctl00$wucLogin1$txtUID" 
    onkeyup="aspxEKeyUp('ctl00_wucLogin1_txtUID', event)"
    type="text" 
    id="ctl00_wucLogin1_txtUID_I" 
    onblur="aspxELostFocus('ctl00_wucLogin1_txtUID')"
    onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('ctl00_wucLogin1_txtUID')"
    onkeypress="aspxEKeyPress('ctl00_wucLogin1_txtUID', event)"
    style="height:15px;">
```

The link for login is :

```
<a id="ctl00_wucLogin1_BtnLogin"
class="Search_button"
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$wucLogin1$BtnLogin','')"
 style="...">Login
</a>
```

How can I click on this link and how can I fill than input for username by twill?
is there any other alternative for twill?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending the `User-Agent` header with the request. In any case, twill doesn't handle JavaScript well, so you're better off trying something else.

For alternatives, there are:

- [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)
- [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/)
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (for parsing HTML)
- [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) ([python bindings](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/#client-drivers))